# How override respect_retry_after_header in urllib3 from requests?

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib, urllib3

When requesting this URL http://www.trouverlesmots.com, this `header` is received back:

```py
{'headers': HTTPHeaderDict({'Date': 'Wed, 20 Nov 2019 18:40:39 GMT', 'Server': 'Apache/2.4.41 (Unix)', 'X-Powered-By': 'PHP/7.1.33', 'Expires': 'Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0', 'Retry-After': '86400', 'Vary': 'User-Agent', 'Connection': 'close', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'}), 'status': 503, 'version': 11, 'reason': 'Service Temporarily Unavailable', 'strict': 0, 'decode_content': False, 'retries': Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None), 'enforce_content_length': False, 'auto_close': True, '_decoder': None, '_body': None, '_fp': <http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x7f2588117940>, '_original_response': <http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x7f2588117940>, '_fp_bytes_read': 7482, 'msg': None, '_request_url': None, '_pool': <urllib3.connectionpool.HTTPConnectionPool object at 0x7f2588117e10>, '_connection': None, 'chunked': True, 'chunk_left': None, 'length_remaining': None}
```

Two parameters are implied:

- `status_code: 503` which implies a `retries` process
- `retry_after: 86400`

`retry_after` is set to `86400` so my `requests.Session()` is pausing for one entire day.

Here is the piece of code commited:

```py
    def sleep_for_retry(self, response=None):
        retry_after = self.get_retry_after(response)
        if retry_after:
            time.sleep(retry_after)  # stops here
            return True

        return False
```

From `urllib3.util.retry.py:277`.

`respect_retry_after_header` may be changed to do not respect the `retry_after` parameter, in the `__init__` of the `Retry` object.

```py
    def __init__(
        self,
        total=10,
        connect=None,
        read=None,
        redirect=None,
        status=None,
        method_whitelist=DEFAULT_METHOD_WHITELIST,
        status_forcelist=None,
        backoff_factor=0,
        raise_on_redirect=True,
        raise_on_status=True,
        history=None,
        respect_retry_after_header=True,
        remove_headers_on_redirect=DEFAULT_REDIRECT_HEADERS_BLACKLIST,
    )
```

From `urllib3.util.retry.py:174`.

Do you know how override that `respect_retry_after` parameter, from my `requests.Session()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While [this answer is likely to work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58961659/481584), the documented way to control retries is to pass a urllib3 `Retry` object to a requests `HTTPAdapter` and mount that adapter on a `Session` object. It works like this:

```py
import urllib3
import requests
import requests.adapters

retry = urllib3.Retry(respect_retry_after_header=False)
adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
session = requests.Session()
session.mount("http://", adapter)
r = session.get("http://www.trouverlesmots.com")
print(r.status_code, r.headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `sleep_for_retry` calls `get_retry_after`, which calls `parse_retry_after` to parse the `Retry-After` header value, you can override `parse_retry_after` with a wrapper function that caps its return value with the `min` function (the example below caps it at 10 seconds):

```
from urllib3.util.retry import Retry
orig_parse_retry_after = Retry.parse_retry_after
Retry.parse_retry_after = lambda self, retry_after: min(10, orig_parse_retry_after(self, retry_after))
```

Comment: It turns out that it's possible to do that without patching Retry, see my answer.